# Deserialize JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am getting a JsonSerializationException and it states that I need a JSON array instead of an array.

```
class Boards
{
    public List<Board> boards { get; set; }        
}

class Board
{
    public string board { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int ws_board { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var boardsJsonLink = "https://a.4cdn.org/boards.json";

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var json = wc.DownloadString(boardsJsonLink);
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Boards>>(json);
```

I get the exception at the last line of code(right above).

Comment: What is the result of this code? What have you tried to print the data to console? See http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Just *serialize* a `Boards` and check the generated string. Json.NET or any parser has no problem parsing a string whether it's formatted or not, as long as it's valid Json.

Comment: I got it guys now I just get an error. @CodeCaster I used json2cSharp. Its very helpful. I also figured out how to output though console as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON isn't List of Boards, it's not even a collection. Your JSON is object with property boards and this property value is collection as well as your **Boards** Class. You should deserialize it to instance of your Boards class.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Boards>(json);
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was this but when I change it the consoles outputs "System.Collection.Generic.List'1[Chan.Board]"

Comment: You didn't mentioned anything about the Console. This solves the problem with deserializing. If you have any other problems share more information :)

Comment: Well right now I'm trying to extract all the information so I can output the data into console and later on display it in a small gui application. If I use "List<Boards>" I was able to write "Console.WriteLine(data[0].board);" but once I run it I get an exception.

Comment: Dude, the data is now object of type Boards. You can access the data with following syntax `Console.WriteLine(data.boards[0].title);  Console.WriteLine(data.boards[0].board);` etc.

Comment: Damn man your right. Been a day since I slept. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following `code`

**TESTED & WORKS FINE**

```
  protected void btntest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var boardsJsonLink = "https://a.4cdn.org/boards.json";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var json = wc.DownloadString(boardsJsonLink);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObj>(json);
        Response.Write(@"<table  width='300px' border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'> <tr>
            <td>
                Board</td>
            <td>
                Title</td>
            <td>
               ws_Board</td>
            <td>
                perPage</td>
            <td>
               pages</td>
        </tr>");
        foreach (var itm in data.boards)
        {
            string board = itm.board;
            string title = itm.title;
            int ws_board = itm.ws_board;
            int per_page = itm.per_page;
            int pages = itm.pages;
            Response.Write(@"<tr>
            <td>"+board+"</td><td>"+Title+"</td><td> "+ws_board+"</td><td> "+ per_page+"</td> <td>"+ pages+"</td></tr>");
        }
        Response.Write(@"</table>");
    }

public class Board
{
    public string board { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int ws_board { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
}

public class TestObj
{
    public List<Board> boards { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE:**
Please *change the class name* as per your requirement.

**Output:**

[image]